# Creating multiple loggers

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have multiple python scripts I run at the same time. They all located in the same directory. One of those is imported in another by "import". In those 2 files I have this:

```
script #1
log_file_name = "logs/somefile_name.log")
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_name) 


script #2
log_file_name = "logs/somefile_name2.log")
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_name)
```

Again, script #2 is imported in script #1 because script #2 has some functions I need in the 1st one.

For some reason I see only one log file, although they have different names. Why is that? I think the settings of creating the logger get overwritten. How to fix it?

Comment: `logging.basicConfig()` is ignored after the first time it is called.  The root logger in the module is meant to be used as a singleton.  If you want to add more log files, you need to add new handlers.

Comment: @apex-meme-lord, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right in the documentation for [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html).

```
log2 = logging.FileHandler('logs/somefile_name2.log')
logging.addHandler(log2)
```

Comment: do I really need "logger = logging.getLogger('something')"?